# Unspecified_Error : "The value for column 'userId' in table "Recipient' is DBNull"

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm currently working with an envelope which contains CompositeTemplates in order to have multiple ediatble PDF. Everything is perfect,except in one particular case :

- My envelope is created ;
- I call "/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents" to add a Document ;
- I call "/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs" to add a tab to this document, associated with an already existing recipient.

DocuSign sent me back an UNSPECIFIED_ERROR with the message "The value for column 'userId' in table "Recipient' is DBNull"...

Here is the corresponding log :

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2/accounts/[accountId]/envelopes/[envelopeId]/recipients/2/tabs

TraceToken: 60fa00cc-41f1-45df-b0ee-0eac83da6b2b
Timestamp: 2017-08-04T13:06:03.1865992Z

Content-Length: 528
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Java-Swagger
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"myMail","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-DocuSign-SDK: Java
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 194.51.78.65

{"approveTabs":[],"checkboxTabs":[],"companyTabs":[],"dateSignedTabs":[],"dateTabs":[],"declineTabs":[],"emailAddressTabs":[],"emailTabs":[],"envelopeIdTabs":[],"firstNameTabs":[],"formulaTabs":[],"fullNameTabs":[],"initialHereTabs":[],"lastNameTabs":[],"listTabs":[],"noteTabs":[],"numberTabs":[],"radioGroupTabs":[],"signerAttachmentTabs":[],"signHereTabs":[],"ssnTabs":[],"textTabs":[{"documentId":"3552","locked":"true","pageNumber":"1","value":"","xPosition":"0","yPosition":"0"}],"titleTabs":[],"viewTabs":[],"zipTabs":[]}
400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 60fa00cc-41f1-45df-b0ee-0eac83da6b2b

{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "The value for column 'UserId' in table 'Recipient' is DBNull."
}
```

Any idea of what can cause this error in my request ? Now, i must admit that I don't realy know what to do, the message is not really helpful...

DocuSign, if you hear me, maybe you should correct your API, in order for this type of message to no be seen by users ?

I'm using the Java API and the demo environment if it can help someone.

Thanks a lot,

Line

EDIT :

I don't specify any port as I use the Java API provided by DocuSign. I check several other successful calls and they use the port 7802 too.

And if I do several calls, it's because don't have any other choice... The document I try to add isn't known when the envelope is created.

Comment: Why are you using port 7802 in your call?

Comment: Have you tried just a single create envelope call? Why do you want to make the multiple calls to create the envelope?

Comment: Hi Larry K ! I made an edit to answer to your question. If it can help you or give you a clue to explain this error... Thanks !

Comment: I hope you are using the below flow for your usecase:

a. POST /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes - To create an envelope
b. PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents - To add a document
c. POST /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/2/tabs    - To update tab of a recipient and you have recipientId - 2 in your envelope

Answer (score 0):

Old bug in DocuSign that was fixed a while ago.
In addition, using API v2.1 is recommended.
Please try this again and report back if you still encounter any problem.